# Can I get the name of the current controller in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, view, controller

Is there a way to figure out what the current controller is from within the view?

For an example of why I would want to know this: if several controllers share the same layout, I may have a part in the layout ERB file where I want to highlight the current page's menu item based on the controller.

Maybe that is a bad approach. If so, what is the more preferred way to do this?

I'm interested to know about getting the name of the current controller either way, though.

(Obviously I could put something like `@controller_name = 'users'` in each controller; but that seems like the sort of thing Rails would've already done behind the scenes. So I'm just wondering if there's a built-in way.)

Answer (score 289, accepted):

`controller_name` holds the name of the controller used to serve the current view.

Comment: Actually is bad practice to use `params` in view.
Please use `controller_name` instead

Comment: @coorasse is right, for sure the information is there, but relying on controller_name is better

Answer (score 277):

Use `controller.controller_name`

In the Rails Guides, it says:

> The params hash will always contain the :controller and :action keys, but you should use the methods **controller_name** and **action_name** instead to access these values

[ActionController Parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#routing-parameters)

So let's say you have a CSS class `active` , that should be inserted in any link whose page is currently open (maybe so that you can style differently) . If you have a `static_pages` controller with an `about` action, you can then highlight the link like so in your view:

```
<li>
  <a class='button <% if controller.controller_name == "static_pages" && controller.action_name == "about" %>active<%end%>' href="/about">
      About Us
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: If you have your controller behind a namespace like this:
`Admin::Orders` then `controller_name` and `params[:controller]` will be `"orders"` and `"admin/orders"` respectively.

Comment: I just tried to use this and `Admin::UsersController` actually has a `controller_name` of `users` and a `controller_path` of `admin/users` in Rails 4.1.0.

Answer (score 94):

```
#to get controller name:
<%= controller.controller_name %>
#=> 'users'

#to get action name, it is the method:
<%= controller.action_name %>
#=> 'show'


#to get id information:
<%= ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path(request.url)[:id] %>
#=> '23'

# or display nicely
<%= debug Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.url) %>
```

[reference](http://ruby-on-rails-tutorials.blogspot.in/2010/11/how-to-get-requested-controller-name.html)

Comment: To get the id, ActionController::Routing::Routes no longer works. You can do this: <%= request.path_parameters[:id] %>

Answer (score 7):

`controller_path` holds the path of the controller used to serve the current view. (ie: `admin/settings`).

and

`controller_name` holds the name of the controller used to serve the current view. (ie: `settings`).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use all stylesheet in your app just adds this line in application.html.erb. Insert it inside `<head>`  tag

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag  controller.controller_name , media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Also, to specify the same class CSS on a different controller
Add this line in the `body` of application.html.erb

```
  <body class="<%= controller.controller_name %>-<%= controller.action_name %>">
```

So, now for example I would like to change the `p` tag in 'home' controller and 'index' action.
Inside `index.scss` file adds.

```
.nameOfController-nameOfAction <tag> { }
```

---

```
 .home-index p {
        color:red !important;
      }
```