# Ruby on Rails : conditionally load scripts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partial-views, yield

**Hey**,

I want to be able to put all of my pages' scripts in my `application` layout, and load each one for the appropriate page.

I came across this [question][1], and I thought I can put the scripts inside of partials and do it the same way that is indicated in the mentioned question, however I'm trying to find the best way for `scripts`.

Would it be something like :

```
yield :scripts if condition
```

or

```
unless condition
 content_for scripts do
 end
end
```

or any other '*best*' way ?

---

*Note: Each page has its own script saved under the same name of the page.*

---

Comment: Here's one solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828767/in-rails-how-to-check-if-javascript-file-exists-before-using-javascript-include

Comment: There's many approaches that might work, but selecting the optimal one depends on a number of conditions. A conditional `yield` isn't a bad plan.

Comment: That's a possible solution, but as you can see I am searching for the simplest. **2 :** I don't need checking for existing, all files do exists, but I need to check for **existing with the same pages' name**. Any other ideas? @DamienRoche

Comment: Can you provide the other approaches I seem to ignore? for I am searching for the simplest aka the best. @tadman

Comment: what is an example of a controller/action and accompanying file name for your JS? Then I can advise how to automatically build that format.

Comment: Pals/index has index.html.erb in the views, and index.js in javascript files dir. @DamienRoche

Comment: So that `index.js` file is for *all* index pages, across *all* controllers?

Comment: No, it is only for the `Pals` controller, and the other controllers have no `js` files, and my website turns around `pals` controller only, barely some 2 or 3 pages of other controllers with unique action names

Comment: Well, you can use `= javascript_include_tag action_name`, but I wouldn't advise it. Better approach is to be more specific in naming structure (`pals_index.js`) and use `= javascript_include_tag [controller_name, action_name].join('_') if -- check if file exists`

Comment: Provide it as an answer, I think it'll be working. Let me try meanwhile.

Comment: I can't provide as an answer because I don't endorse it ;) it's a nasty hack and will not catch any number of edge cases.

Comment: Btw, how the hell am I supposed to get the controller_name, and action name? XD?

Comment: the `controller_name` and `action_name` should already be accessible from inside your views? They are helper methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

I relied on the recommendations of @damien at the comments with the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828767/in-rails-how-to-check-if-javascript-file-exists-before-using-javascript-include) he provided to come up with something like this:

In my helpers:

```
def javascript_exists?(script)
  script = "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/javascripts/#{[params[:controller], params[:action]].join('_')}.js"
  File.exists?(script) || File.exists?("#{script}.coffee") 
end
```

In my application layout:

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag [params[:controller], params[:action]].join('_'), :media => "all"  if javascript_exists?([params[:controller], params[:action]].join('_')) %>
```

So to each controller, and to each action in the controller, the appropriate ***.js*** file gets included if it exists.