# Rails: How to determine what page user is viewing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example, I have a footer

```
<%= link_to 'Tweets', tweets_path %>
<%= link_to 'Blogs', blogs_path %>
```

In the Tweets Index Page, I want to hide the `<%= link_to 'Tweets', tweets_path %>`. and show something else. How do I know what `resource` the user is currently on?

Specifically, I want to

```
resources = ['Tweet', 'Blog']   # get the model names, and there maybe something more to be added later
resources.each do  |resource|
  if controller.controller_name = resource  &&  controller.method_name = 'index'
      link_to new_resource_path  # for example, link_to new_tweet_path
  else 
      link_to resource_path   # for example, link_to tweets_path 
  end
end
```

The rough Idea is above. But in `controller.controller_name` and `link_to` method, I do not know the details of writing it.

I find `controller.controller_name` from [Can I get the name of the current controller in the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757491/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-current-controller-in-the-view) 
What would be a good way to do this?

UPDATE:

```
def footer_helper
  resources = ['tweet', 'blog']   # and perhaps something more
  resources.each do  |resource|
     if current_page?(controller: resource.pluralize, action: 'index')
        link_to "New #{resource.humanize}", {controller: resource.pluralize, action: 'new'}
      else
        link_to "#{resource.pluralize.humanize}", {controller: resource.pluralize, action: 'index'}
     end
  end
end
```

end

Now I've made it into a helper like above. But I find the `.pluralize` and `.humanize` irritating, is there any way to get rid of them?

Also, how can I use it in views? when I use `<%= footer_helper %>`, it shows `["tweet", "blog"]`. It does not return properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`current_page?`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3F) helper:

```
resources = ['tweet', 'blog']
resources.each do  |resource|
  if current_page?(controller: resource, action: 'index')
    link_to(resource.humanize, { controller: resource, action: 'new' })
  else 
    link_to(resource.humanize, { controller: resource, action: 'index' })
  end
end
```

This can be improved with the [`link_to_if`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if) helper:

```
resources = ['tweet', 'blog']
resources.each do  |resource|
  link_to_if(current_page?(controller: resource, action: 'index'), resource.humanize, {controller: resource, action: 'new'}) do
    link_to(resource.humanize, {controller: resource, action: 'index'})
  end
end
```

When you don't want the computer-gerenated interface texts (this often is a bad idea), consider making the resources a `Hash`, like so:

```
resources = {'tweets' => "Tweet", 'blogs' => "Blog"}
resources.each do  |resource, name|
  link_to_if(current_page?(controller: resource, action: 'index'), name, {controller: resource, action: 'new'}) do
    link_to(name, {controller: resource, action: 'index'})
  end
end
```

Comment: How can I pass `new_resource_path` to `link_to`? I mean, `resource` is just a string here. But I need to pass a `path` to the `link_to` method

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that. Edited!

Comment: Now I'm trying to make it into a Helper and use it in view. But the output has some problem, could you help me on this? I put it on the UPDATE

Comment: »But I find the .pluralize and .humanize irritating, is there any way to get rid of them?« Well, yes, by not attempting to create interface texts through code. See the update in my post.

Answer (score 2):

`params[:action]` will show you what action they were routed too and likewise `params[:controller]` will find out which controller that action is in.  You can use these to write some logic for your footer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice gem for it, for tidy code:

https://github.com/robotmay/link_to_active_state

This gem adds a small bit of extra functionality to the default Rails link_to view helper. It provides a very simple way of adding classes to links based on the current path.

Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method:

```
# application_helper.rb

module ApplicationHelper
  def body_id
    [body_class, params[:action]].join('-')
  end

  def body_class
    controller.class.to_s.gsub('Controller', '').underscore.dasherize.gsub('/', '-')
  end
end
```

In my layout:

```
# application.html.erb

<body id="<%= body_id %>" class="<%= body_class %>">
</body>
```

So for `TweetsController#index`, this renders

```
<body id="tweets-index" class="tweets">
```

Now you can apply CSS depending on the controller or controller action the user is on:

```
body#tweets-index a.tweet-links {
  display: none;
}
```