# How can I test if the current page is in a given path/controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following routes

```
  resources :tracking_categories do
    resources :trackings
  end
```

I have the following view and I'd like to highlight the button if anywhere inside the `/tracking_categories` path, ex: `http://localhost:3000/tracking_categories/6/trackings/new`. I tried [current_page?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F)

```
  %li{class: current_page?(controller: 'tracking_categories') ? 'active' : false}
    =link_to 'Track My Progress', new_tracking_category_tracking_path(1)
```

I also tried

```
%li{class: current_page?(controller: 'trackings') ? 'active' : false}
```

I also tried [#url](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/URL.html#method-i-url)

```
  %li{class: url.index('tracking_categories') ? 'active' : false}
```

They all return false, except `url`, which gives the error

> wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)

Answer (score 2):

You can use params[:action] and params[:controller].

[Routing parameters documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#routing-parameters)

[Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757491/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-current-controller-in-the-view) suggesting that you can use:

```
controller.controller_name == "the_controller_I_want_to_check"
controller.action_name == "the_action_I_want_to_check"
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
%li{class: request.original_url.index('tracking_categories') ? 'active' : false}
```