# How do I show the name of a page I am on in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, header

I have a header as follows

Home

But I want the name of the current page to be dynamic. For example when I visit the articles page the title should say articles, and The locations pages should say locations.

I am new to Ruby and Rails so this is probably very easy but I don't know how. Thanks in advance!

James

Comment: One way to do it is define an instance variable in your controller. For example, in your articles controller, before you render the view, `@page = 'Articles'`. Then in the view you can use `@page`. It's not clear to me, though, exactly what you mean when you say the name is "dynamic".

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757491/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-current-controller-in-the-view

Answer (score 2):

Inside `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` replace `<title>...</title>` by

```
<title>
  <% if content_for?(:title) %>
    <%= yield :title %>
  <% end %>
</title>
```

You'll be able to change the title dynamically from any other view, for instance:

```
# app/views/articles/index.html.erb

<% content_for(:title) do %>
  Articles
<% end %>
```

```
# app/views/locations/index.html.erb

<% content_for(:title) do %>
  Locations
<% end %>
```

Let's assume that you have `@article` object with `name` field

```
# app/views/articles/show.html.erb

<% content_for(:title) do %>
  @article.name
<% end %>
```

**UPD**

As suggested by @engineersmnky you can pass the title as a parameter `content_for(:title, 'Articles')`

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for

Comment: Thanks for getting back Yakov. So basically there's a small title in my _nav.html.erb file and it is hardcoded at Home. So when I go to all the pages it still says home. Whereas I would like this small title to change to the page I'm currently on. Be a bit more dynamic! I feel like it should be one line of code. I don't want to have to change the title in every view! That may be the only way to do it but I'm not sure! Thanks

Comment: There is a link under you question provided by @spickermann. The solution based on a controller name.

Comment: A title in `_nav.html.erb` could be added using breadcrumbs https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Breadcrumb_Builders

Comment: Could make this a bit cleaner by just using `content_for(:title, 'Articles')` rather than the block syntax

Answer (score 0):

In Your project folder open app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.
This file contains head tag of every page in standard namespace of Your application.
Name of page is inside of title tag. You can change it dynamicly by using <%= %> tag.